# DOUBLE_CLICK dont work in actionscript3 

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs3

I have

```
MyMovie.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, goClick)
function goClick(e:MouseEvent):void
{
trace("Trololo");
}
```

It's work.

Why don't work?

```
MyMovie.addEventListener(MouseEvent.DOUBLE_CLICK, goDouble)
function goDouble(e:MouseEvent):void
{
trace("Trololo");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set [doubleClickEnabled](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#doubleClickEnabled) to true.

```
MyMovie.doubleClickEnabled = true;
```